# Define Kotlin's detekt version as extra property (ext)

Tags: gradle, kotlin, detekt

Groovy allows definition of *extra properties* for the project in `ext`.

I wanted to define Detekt's version inside groovy's extra properties. Detekt is a static code analysis tool for Kotlin lang.

However when I do it in the folloing way:

```
buildscript {
    // testing, code-style, CI-tools
    ext.detect_code_analysis = '1.0.0.RC6-3' //change to 1.0.0 when available

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
plugins {
    id "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt" version "$detect_code_analysis"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

detekt {
    version = "$detect_code_analysis"
    profile("main") {
        input = "$projectDir/app/src/main/java"
        config = "$projectDir/detekt-config.yml"
        filters = ".*test.*,.*/resources/.*,.*/tmp/.*"
    }
}
```

it complaing with:

```
Error:(17, 0) startup failed:
        build file '/Users[...]build.gradle': 17: argument list must be exactly 1 literal non empty string

See https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block

@ line 17, column 5.
        id "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt" version "$detect_code_analysis"
^

1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“New style” Gradle plug-in definition (without including the full dependency on `buildscript` block) does not allow variables in the version.

For more information refer to the section of documentation that’s referred to in the error message. There is a subsection “Limitations of the plugins dsl” that explains everything.

If you want to continue using the variable version strings you need to return to the “old way” by using the `apply plugin: “xxx”` syntax.

Comment: yes, thanks - it works as expected. I needed to add classpath in buildscript.dependecies, and change `plugins` to `apply plugin: "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt"`

Comment: link: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations  Explains the limitations and WHY they exist.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables in `plugins {}`: [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax)

> Where «plugin version» and «plugin id» must be constant, literal

This is an open bug: [Allow the plugin DSL to expand properties as the version](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1697)

Comment: OK, let's hope it gets fixed soon

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not a bug, but an intentional design decision. In order to support faster builds, having the plugins section be hard-coded supports that. If there's a variable involved, Gradle has to do much more work/compiling to determine if the build has changed, and do work for that. They are investigating ways of maintaining the performance while providing variables, but thus far...

Comment: link: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations  Explains the limitations and WHY they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Strelok suggested the final workaround (until [bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1697) is fixed) is to:

- add a classpath in *buildscript.dependecies*
- change `plugins` to `apply plugin: "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt"`

Solution:

```
buildscript {

    // testing, code-style, CI-tools
    ext.detect_code_analysis = '1.0.0.RC6-3' //change to 1.0.0 when available

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:$detect_code_analysis"
    }
}

apply plugin: "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

detekt {
    version = "$detect_code_analysis"
    profile("main") {
        input = "$projectDir/app/src/main/java"
        config = "$projectDir/detekt-config.yml"
        filters = ".*test.*,.*/resources/.*,.*/tmp/.*"
    }
}
```